# CameraView isn't switching

Tags: android, camera

I'm developing a small camera app.

**Details:**

> I have floating action buttons that switch the camera view from back
>   to front to back again. I have more than one buttons so i have a
>   switch statement inside my onClick method.

**Problem:**

> I used an if statement and integer to determine whether the camera is
>   facing back or front. (in theory it should work, right?) but when i
>   run it, the icon of the button changes, which is supposed to be
>   accompanied by a change of the camera view as well. also, after
>   clicking it once, it gets stuck, i cant change it back.

**Note:** I used the **Flurge camerKit library** to access the camera.

can anyone guide me what's wrong in my code?

thanks in advance!

**Here's my code:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.floatingActionButton2:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            break;

        case R.id.frontcam:

            if ((cameraFront % 2) == 0 ){ //by default int cameraFront = 1

                cameraView.setFacing(CameraKit.Constants.FACING_FRONT);
                frontCamera.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_camera_front_white_24dp);
                break;

            }

            else {

                cameraView.setFacing(CameraKit.Constants.FACING_BACK);
                frontCamera.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_camera_rear_white_24dp);
                break;

            }

//more code stuff

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private int getFrontCameraID() {
    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        return CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    }
    return getBackCameraID();
}
```

call on button click

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCameraID == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                mCameraID = getBackCameraID();
            } else {
                mCameraID = getFrontCameraID();
            }
            restartPreview();
        }
    });

  private void restartPreview() {
    try {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            stopCameraPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            //mCamera = null;
        }
        getCamera(mCameraID);
        startCameraPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```